# Nativescript-vue, How to change BarSeries(Radchart) graph "bars" color?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

Code:

```
<BarSeries v-tkCartesianSeries
             categoryProperty="Country"
             valueProperty="Amount"
             :items="items1" />
<CategoricalAxis v-tkCartesianVerticalAxis />
<LinearAxis v-tkCartesianHorizontalAxis />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to define `Palette` with same series name

```
            <BarSeries v-tkCartesianSeries :items="items1"
                categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount"
                seriesName="myLine" />
            <Palette v-tkCartesianPalette seriesName="myLine">
                <PaletteEntry v-tkCartesianPaletteEntry strokeWidth="5"
                    strokeColor="red" fillColor="red"></PaletteEntry>
            </Palette>
            <CategoricalAxis v-tkCartesianHorizontalAxis />
            <LinearAxis v-tkCartesianVerticalAxis />
```

Comment: You don't need a Palette

Answer (score -1):

Just use `fillColor` and `strokeColor` in the BarSeries

```
<RadCartesianChart>
   <CategoricalAxis v-tkCartesianHorizontalAxis />
   <LinearAxis v-tkCartesianVerticalAxis />
   <BarSeries v-tkCartesianSeries :items="items" categoryProperty="" valueProperty="" fillColor="red" />
</RadCartesianChart>
```